# Debian 9.1 Set Chmod 777 to 2 files while it is not working

Tags: php, linux, debian, chmod

I am trying to setup **cryptodice**, but to so the setup, I need on 2 files chmod 777! Well, those 2 files are: `inc/db-conf.php` and `inc/driver-conf.php`!

So I executed this command: `find /CryptoDice -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;` this should set every file in the directory to chmod 777. But when I reload te page. It still says that it is not write able. How can I fix this?

I know that it is not good to have that chmod 777. I would like to set that to the default again after the install, so it will be secure again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your find command is finding directories is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Progrock I wont those files to be chmod 777

Comment: Then you need to chmod the files no?  And if you want to add additional files to those directories by the web server, the parent directories need to be writable.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the install instructions at: https://github.com/felinegambler/CryptoDice

> 3) Change to the inc/ directory and change the permissions to 777
>   (chmod 777 *)

You could simply do something like the following:

```
$ chmod 777 inc/db-conf.php
$ chmod 777 inc/driver-conf.php
```